# Migrate from IIF to CASE statements in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a requirement where we have to migrate from MS Access to SQL Server.

We have a where clause like :

```
WHERE (((IIf([ATTD_Region_CD]='ALL',True,IIf([ATTD_Region_CD]='NI' And    
[Region_CD]<>'002' And [Region_CD]<>'007',True,IIf([ATTD_Region_CD]=
[Region_CD],True,False))))<>False)
```

Now I have use a SQL Server `CASE` statement instead of `IIF` in my query which is following:

```
WHERE
(
    Case 
       when qryRPT_POSendTasks_Tasks.ATTD_Region_CD = 'ALL' 
       then @Out = true 
       else
(case 
    when (qryRPT_POSendTasks_Tasks.ATTD_Region_CD='NI' 
and qryRPT_POSendTasks_VendorRegion.Region_CD<>'002' 
and qryRPT_POSendTasks_VendorRegion.Region_CD<>'007' 
then @Out=true 
else (
case when qryRPT_POSendTasks_Tasks.ATTD_Region_CD    
=qryRPT_POSendTasks_VendorRegion.Region_CD 
then @Out= true 
else @Out=false 
end 
)
```

end
   )
   end
   <>false)

I have declare the `@Out` as `bit`.

Now after executing the query I get error:

> Incorrect syntax near '='.

I have to check the result of `CASE` statement if true or false.

Please anybody help me regarding this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just as an aside though you are not using the specific version, do note [IIF()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) is available in SQL Server 2012 - onwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem to need a `CASE` expression - just logic:

```
WHERE [ATTD_Region_CD]='ALL' OR
([ATTD_Region_CD]='NI' And [Region_CD] not in ('002','007')) OR
([ATTD_Region_CD]=[Region_CD])
```